# how to flatten (n, ) shape numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a variable called data, and i want to flatten it.

Right now `data.shape = (10, )`. Each element in data has a shape (5000, 64). I want to make my `data.shape = (10, 5000, 64)`.

How can I do that? I've tried many below, but none of them work:

```
b = np.concatenate(t for t in data)
b = np.stack(t for t in data)
b = np.hstack(t for t in data)
```

anyone any idea about this?

Comment: please add some example of what you tried, what you expect and what the result was

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [50]: t = np.zeros(3,object)
In [51]: t[0]=np.ones((3,2),int)
In [52]: t[1]=np.ones((3,2),int)
In [53]: t[2]=np.ones((3,2),int)
In [54]: t
Out[54]: 
array([array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]]),
       array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]]),
       array([[1, 1],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 1]])], dtype=object)
In [55]: np.stack(t)
Out[55]: 
array([[[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]],

       [[1, 1],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 1]]])
In [56]: _.shape
Out[56]: (3, 3, 2)
```

`np.stack(x for x in t)` also works, but the extra layer of iteration isn't needed.

When you say something isn't working, you need to elaborate.  What exactly was the error?  Was it the same error for each of things you tried?  Without information like that you'll get answers like mine - a test case that appears to match your description which works.

`hstack` works, but joins the arrays in a different way.

`concatenate` doesn't work with the `(t for t in x)` input, but is ok with `(x)`.

Assuming my guess about it being a object dtype array is right, this isn't a case of `flatten`.  `numpy` flatten is like ravel, a shape changer.  But this is different.  I have arrays inside an object array, effectively a list of arrays, not a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The problem is that my data is a numpy array of tensors, and you have to use tf.stack to do the thing.